# How do I properly type an array of Classes in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a set of classes that I'd like to put in an array without instantiation. The challenge is properly typing that array in Typescript.

I'm currently using the generic 'Object[]' type and would like something more specific.

The code below throws an error in this regard as its not instantiated

```js
abstract class Foo{
    abstract test():boolean;
}

class Bar extends Foo{
    test():boolean{return true}
}

class Lorem extends Foo{
    test():boolean{return true}
}

let arr:Foo[] = [
    Bar,
    Lorem
];
```

As it stands the error thrown here is

> Property 'test' is missing in type 'typeof Lorem' but required in type
> 'Foo'.ts(2741)

The use case here is to be able to dynamically instantiate a list of Foo Classes depending on the context within which it is called

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N9AOVN), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: What specific error are you seeing, and where?  You could possibly fix this with `let arr: Array<new(...args: any)=>any>`, or something more specific, but I don't even see a problem in this code as-is.  Surely you want to be able to do something "class-constructor-ish" with these class constructors, but there's no use case described or shown.

Comment: @jcalz you're right, I edited the question for just that. now if you put this in the IDE it should throw an error

Comment: (Deleted previous comment).  Okay, wait, I guess I see your use case written out as words.  Good enough.

Comment: `(typeof Foo)[]` is what you're looking for, I think. There should be another question that this can be marked as a duplicate of, though.

Comment: I doubt `typeof Foo` will work if the use case is to call `new arr[0]()`

Comment: `let arr: Array<new () => Foo>`?  That requires that it can be constructed with no arguments. https://tsplay.dev/WP5gJw  Or if your actual use case has args then ` Array<new (something: string) => Foo>` etc.

Comment: Yeah, the code from other questions would be translated here as something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8vXdm).  You want `new () => Foo`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste that seems to be the best answer there. If you answer it i'll accept

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the help